# C: strtok delivers segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, tokenize

I am trying to read a file line by line, and tokenize each line, which have strings separated by spaces and tabs. However, when I run my program, I get the a `Segmentation Fault` error when I try to print the token. I don't understand why this is happening, as I am using a buffer as the string to tokenize and checking if the token is null. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 70

int main(void)
{
    FILE * testFile;
    char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    testFile = fopen("test_file.txt", "r");

    if (testFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open test_file.txt.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

     while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), testFile) != NULL) {
        char *token = strtok(buf," \t"); 


        while (token != NULL) 
        {
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t"); 

            if (token != NULL) {
             printf("%s\n", token);
            }
        }
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

Below is the contents of `test_file.txt`:

```
String1 String2 String3
String4 String5 String6
String7 String8 String9
```

Comment: Why don't you check the token before passing to printf?

Comment: Use a debugger. At the very minimum it will tell you which line of code seg faults. You can also examine the variables and step the code.

Comment: You don't check the return value of strtok.

Comment: Don't *Hardcode Filenames* or use *Magic Numbers* (you did a good job with `#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 70`), but pass the filename as the first argument to your program (that's why you have the invocation `int main (int argc, char **argv)`), or take the filename as input. Also use `" \t\n"` as your delimiter so you get rid of the trailing `'\n'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two helpful tips -- (1) *enable compiler warnings*, e.g. minimum `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS (any other compiler will have similar options), and do not accept code until it compiles without warning; (2) `#include <string.h>` where `strtok` is defined.

In addition to the lack of validation pointed out by @dreamer, you must be using an implicit definition for `strtok`. You should receive a compiler warning along those lines. Don't ignore any warning, instead go fix it, it will generally tell you the exact line the problem code is on.

Next, don't hardcode filenames. It is just as simple to pass the filename as the first argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default). Your second option is to take the filename as input to your program.

Putting those together, you could do something simple like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 70
#define DELIM " \t\n"

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, fp))
        for (char *p = strtok(buf, DELIM); p; p = strtok(NULL, DELIM))
            puts (p);

    if (fp != stdin)   /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you need to include `'\n'` as a delimiter character to prevent the additional `'\n'` from being part of the last token in each line)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtokfile test_file.txt
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
String6
String7
String8
String9
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are printing without checking for NULL for token pointer.

If you need to print all tokens you also need to print inside while loop after strtok system call with addition to non-NULL check for token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added the changes you mentioned, but I still get a segmentation fault error. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Have you forgotten to `#include <string.h>`? -- and are ignoring the implicitly defined `strtok` warning?

Comment: Looks like problem is with the hardcoded MAX_LINE_LENGTH 70 value. You need to read complete file into dynamic char buffer first, then iterate over this complete string buffer to get correct output.